# Gradle Error - "Error:arm64-v8a|x86|x86_64|mips|mips64' for type 'abiType'."

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a strange error. When I try build any app in my Android Studio (checked in 2.3.3 and 3.0.1) I get about 20 errors:

> Error:arm64-v8a|x86|x86_64|mips|mips64' for type 'abiType'.:

In spite of it gradle build app and deploy it on device (everything is working properly actually), but it's annoying having so many errors.
Did anyone have the same problem?

I've tried clean project, invalidate cache, reinstall android studio (I've checked 2.3.3 and 3.0.1). Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing minSdkVersion may resolve this.

I had the 4 same errors ("Error:arm64-v8a|x86|x86_64|mips|mips64' for type 'abiType'.:").

Google brought me to this page https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html,
where there was information,p that some ABIs (mips and mips64) were deprecated in r16 and wIll be removed in r17.

So I changed minSdkVersion from 15 to 18 and the errors are gone.

P.S. Errors did not affect the performance of the application, so I returned the minimum version of the SDK back to 15.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18442402)

Comment: The question was "Did anyone have the same problem?", so I answered it) Seriously, I replied that I was helped by an increase in the minimum version of SDK